# python - Why can extend modify a value without a global designation?

Tags: python

```
>>> x = []
>>> y = [1,2,3]
>>> def func1(L):
...     x+=L
... 
>>> def func2(L):
...     x.extend(L)
... 
>>> func1(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in func1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
>>> func2(y)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
```

Why can the list extend() method alter the non-global variable, but the += operator cannot? From what I understand, as long as the function doesn't assign the variable, it can read it without the global designation. but in this case the function does set the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't set the value, it modifies the existing value.  In Python binding a name to a value is one thing, and modifying (or mutating) a value is another thing.

The real question is why `+=` *doesn't* work, since for lists this operation is defined to also modify the list in-place.  The answer is just that, because that operator looks like assignment, it was decided to make it act like assignment for scoping and binding purposes.  [The documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) says (emphasis added):

> An augmented assignment *evaluates the target* (which, unlike normal assignment statements, cannot be an unpacking) and the expression list, performs the binary operation specific to the type of assignment on the two operands, and *assigns the result to the original target*.

In other words, augmented assignment includes an assignment as part of the operation, so the normal scoping/binding rules apply.  Since the target is evaluated as a target, if it's a function it's treated as a local variable.  So when `x` is a list, `x += newList` is effectively like:

```
x.extend(newList)
x = x
```

More generally, augmented assignment can modify the operand in-place, but it still then attempts to rebind the resulting value to the original variable.  So `x += other` works essentially like:

```
y = x.__iadd__(other)
x = y
```